# how to Show data in the tab of product detail page?

Tags: magento2

I have to do same work as detail tab is doing on product detail page . I have added a tab named as technical details on product detail page. Also I have added technical detail section for each product on backend. Now I want to show the data of technical detail in the tab of product detail page. kindly tell me what I have to do ??
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please find in **`app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`** and find this tab : **referenceBlock name="product.info.details** than add below code inside tab..

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test.tab" template="Magento_Catalog::technical_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Technical Details</argument>
</arguments>
```

and than create one file with below code with this path : **`app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/technical_tab.phtml`** :

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php echo $product->getData('technical_details'); ?>
```